# Custom chrome extension not launching device list

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I'm trying to launch the cast api from a chrome extension that i'm writing. When I run this same code in a regular old HTML file on my webserver, it works perfectly. It doesn't work when I use this code in the popup of my extension. The requestSession call doesn't work at all in that case and nothing seems to happen after it's called.

I believe the expected behaviour is that the google cast extension will show the device list popup. Here is my javascript and html. Most of it is copied right out of CastHelloVideo-chrome.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Popup</title>
    <style>
        body {
            min-width:5px;
            overflow-x:hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="castButton">Cast!</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
//Constants
var applicationID = "<App ID>";
var session;
var currentMediaSession;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Chromecast API
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if (!chrome.cast || !chrome.cast.isAvailable) {
  setTimeout(initializeCastApi, 1000);
}

function loadMedia() {
  if (!session) {
    console.log("no session");
    return;
  }
  var mediaInfo = new chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/big_buck_bunny_1080p.mp4');
  mediaInfo.contentType = 'video/mp4';
  var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
  request.autoplay = false;
  request.currentTime = 0;

  session.loadMedia(request,
    onMediaDiscovered.bind(this, 'loadMedia'),
    onMediaError);

}

/**
 * callback on success for loading media
 * @param {Object} e A non-null media object
 */
function onMediaDiscovered(how, mediaSession) {
  console.log("new media session ID:" + mediaSession.mediaSessionId);
  currentMediaSession = mediaSession;
}

/**
 * callback on media loading error
 * @param {Object} e A non-null media object
 */
function onMediaError(e) {
  console.log("media error");
}



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//UI
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var castbutton = document.getElementById("castButton");
castButton.onclick=function(){
    window.close();
    chrome.cast.requestSession(onRequestSessionSuccess, onLaunchError);
//  loadMedia();
};


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Helper Functions
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function initializeCastApi() {
  var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(applicationID);
  var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
    sessionListener,
    receiverListener);
  chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, onInitSuccess, onError);
}

function sessionListener(e) {
     console.log('New session ID: ' + e.sessionId);
     session = e;
}

function receiverListener(e) {
    console.log(e);
}

function onInitSuccess() {
  console.log("init success");
}

function onError() {
  console.log("error");
}

function onSuccess(message) {
  console.log(message);
}

function onRequestSessionSuccess(e) {
    session = e;
    console.log("session created");
}

 function onLaunchError(e) {
    console.log(e.description);
 }
```

I think this may be caused because I'm trying to run this out of the popup of my extension. Maybe chrome doesn't allow multiple plugins to show their (the device list is google cast's popup) popup window's at the same time? I've tried closing the popup before executing the requestSession call, but it still doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you tried doing this without a popup?

Comment: No errors whatsoever. It works fine if I just open the html file and try it. It's definitely the popup that's causing the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I've never dealt with chrome extensions before, but how do you call the popup window? Is it specific to the Chrome extension API or generic javascript like `alert()`?

Comment: The popup window is the html that's displayed when you click the extension's icon in your toolbar. So when you click the google cast extension icon you get the list of devices, that is that extension's popup window. In the extension config files you just define the html file to be displayed, which I gave the code for above.

Comment: So you're unable to open the chrome cast device list popup from your  extension's own popup?

Comment: Invoking requestionSession API call within a Chrome extension is not supported. That's why you cannot get a list of devices.

In any case this method call only works from a regular web page and it triggers the extension to show a pop-up of Cast devices.  That's the current way it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking requestionSession API call within a Chrome extension is not supported. That's why you cannot get a list of devices.

In any case this method call only works from a regular web page and it triggers the extension to show a pop-up of Cast devices.  That's the only current way it's supposed to work.

Comment: Is there anyway I can get around it? Unless it's explicitly forbidden, is there maybe some method in the cast_sender.js file that I can call manually to make the api think it's being run on a standard page?

Comment: Another method I was considering is maybe doing something like a user script to inject the script tag into a the page that has my content and then execute the api calls. Unfortunately with this method, chrome.cast seems to be undefined.

Comment: Chrome extensions have isolation between the page's javascript and extension's javascript, but they both share the same DOM. Maybe, that's why you can't access chrome.cast from extension. Were you able to get this working? I'm stuck in the same place and one possible solution i can think of is to use DOM somehow to transfer message from extension -> page -> chromecast